Feedback on graph theory proof?
I'm trying to reteach myself graph theory (for fun) after having taken it a few years back during COVID and wishing I had a better grasp of it. Would anyone be willing to provide feedback on the following proof? Most advanced math classes were remote for me so I am not great at proofs. Any feedback is appreciated!
Proposition: The isomorphism relation is an equivalence relation on the set of simple graphs.
Proof: Let $G$ be a simple graph and $f: V(G) → V(G)$ be a bijection such that $f(v)=v$ for all $v \in V$. Then $uv \in E(G)$ if and only if $f(u)f(v) \in E(G)$, and $G \cong G$, proving the isomorphism relation on the set of simple graphs is reflexive.
Now, let $G$ and $H$ be simple isomorphic graphs with $f:V(G) → V(H)$. Then $uv \in E(G)$ if and only if $f(u)f(v) \in E(H)$. Now consider the bijection $f^{-1}: V(H) → V(G)$ such that $f(u)f(v) \in E(H)$ if and only if $f^{-1}(u)f^{-1}(v) \in E(G)$, an isomorphism from $H$ to $G$. It follows that $G \cong H$ implies $H \cong G$, satisfying the symmetric property.
Finally, let $G \cong H$ and $H \cong F$ with $f: V(G) → V(H)$ and $g: V(H) → V(F)$. Then $uv \in E(G)$ if and only if $f(u)f(v) \in E(H)$ and $f(u)f(v) \in E(H)$ if and only if $g(f(u))g(f(v)) \in E(F)$. It follows that $uv \in E(G)$ if and only if $g(f(u))g(f(v)) \in E(F)$, satisfying an isomorphism of the composite function $g \circ f: V(G) → V(F)$ which demonstrates an isomorphism between $G$ and $F$, proving the isomorphism relation is transitive.
Since it has been proven that the isomorphism relation satisfies the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties, it follows that the isomorphism relation is an equivalence relation on the set of simple graphs. $\square$

"It follows that $f(v)=v.$" This is not true. You can show $f(v)=v$ is a graph isomorphism, but you can't assert that all isomorphisms from $G$ to $G$ are $f(v)=v.$ For example, if $G$ is a graph with no edges, there are idifferent somorphisms $G\to G$ for any permutation of the nodes.

Luckily, you don't want to show that all isomorphisms $G$ to $G$ are the identity. You want that an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$ exists, and you can easily show that $f(v)=v$ is such an isomorphism.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks so much -- I appreciate the feedback. Question - why don't I have to show that all isomorphisms G to G are the identity? Don't I have to show that all isomorphisms are reflexive?

@ThomasAndrews Made an edit to that first paragraph. Does that work for showing just that $f(v)=v$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$?

For reflexivity, you need only show that every graph is isomorphic to itself, and for that it suffices to show that for any graph there exists an automorphism (isomorphism from its vertex set to its vertex set). And for that job, the identity function on the vertex set does indeed suffice, as you have shown.

Your proof is too verbose. You have to prove that a graph is isomorphic to itself and the identity is the obvious choice. You have done that. For symmetry and transitivity, we are given that the graphs are isomorphic so we don't have to construct isomorphisms. We know that the inverse of an isomorphism is an isomorphism and we can use the inverses of two isomorphisms to show that the composition of two isomorphisms is an isomorphism.
